# How to create an origin-destination matrix from dataframe for academic mobility across institutions

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create links between organisations (nodes) based on changes in the affiliation of researchers. The ultimate goal would be to have a time-varying network of mobility flows where the origin and destination is an institution rather than a city or a country, but it is essentially the same as having a geographical location. However, contrary to mobility from place A to place B, a researcher can be connected to multiple affiliations/organizations at the same time. This complicates the creation of origin-destination matrices.

My dataset looks something like this :

| researcher_id | publication_id | year | org |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2012 | A |
| 1 | 2 | 2014 | B |
| 1 | 2 | 2014 | C |
| 1 | 3 | 2014 | D |

From the table we can see that researcher #1 (*researcher id*) published 3 papers (*publication id*) in total, the first publication was in 2012 with affiliation A, the second and third publications in 2014 for which second publication (#2) was published with two affiliations to B and C and the third publication (#3) with affiliation D.

From this data, I want to create a dataframe like so:

| researcher_id | origin | destination | year_move |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 2014 |
| 1 | A | C | 2014 |
| 1 | A | D | 2014 |
| 1 | B | C | 2014 |
| 1 | C | B | 2014 |
| 1 | B | D | 2014 |
| 1 | D | C | 2014 |
| 1 | C | D | 2014 |

Since publications #2 and #3 were published in the same year, I do not want to assume a direction (i.e., which is the origin and which is the destination), so I would like to create links between all the organisations instead.

For those moves for which the year is lower than the following year, which is the case of publication #1 I assume that A is the only origin, therefore, a directed edge needs to be created, as is the case with the move from organisation A-> B, C, D.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
for(i in 1:length(df$researcher_id)){
  df$origin[i]=df$org[i]
  df$destination[i]=df$org[i+1]  
  df$move[i]=ifelse(df$orig[i]!=df$dest[i] & df$researcher_id[i]==df$researcher_id[i+1],1,0) #Checking whether a move has taken place and whether it's the same person
  df$year_move[i]=(df$year[i+1])
}

df_moves=df[df$move!=0,c("researcher_id", "origin","destination","year_move")]
```

I hope the question is clear enough :)
Thank you in advance for your help.